# Handling JSON array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, aws-lambda

I'm trying to work with the following incoming json in a Python script running in an AWS Lambda function.  This is coming into Lambda on the usual event object as a dict.

```
{
    "WirelessDeviceId": "AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEE",
    "AddedDeviceDecoderType": "TEST",
    "PayloadData": "Aw==",
    "WirelessMetadata": {
      "LoRaWAN": {
        "ADR": true,
        "Bandwidth": 125,
        "ClassB": false,
        "CodeRate": "4/5",
        "DataRate": "3",
        "DevAddr": "LMNOP123",
        "DevEui": "DPLAMSD010101",
        "FCnt": 42,
        "FOptLen": 1,
        "FPort": 4,
        "Frequency": "905100000",
        "Gateways": [
          {
            "GatewayEui": "ABC123",
            "Rssi": -109,
            "Snr": 8
          }
        ],
        "MIC": "ABC900000",
        "MType": "UnconfirmedDataUp",
        "Major": "LoRaWANR1",
        "Modulation": "LORA",
        "PolarizationInversion": false,
        "SpreadingFactor": 7,
        "Timestamp": "2021-08-08T16:04:10Z"
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm struggling with the "Gateways" array, which may have anywhere from 1 to 10 entries.

Right now, during testing I only have one gateway, and am addressing it in Python like this.

```
rssi = event['WirelessMetadata']['WirelessMetadata']['Gateways'][0]['Rssi']
```

But when new gateways are added, I won't know how many Gateways will be inside that array, nor will I know what index they are assigned to so very quickly hard-coding the [0] will not work.

Newbie question, but what is the best way to handle that case?  I thought it might have something to do with looping through the array, but I struggled a bit to understand best practice.

Comment: Getaway is a a list of dict, so you can retrieve the list and iterate on it.

Comment: `for gw in event['WirelessMetadata']['WirelessMetadata']['Gateways']: do something with gw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the list of gateways.

```py
gateways = event['WirelessMetadata']['WirelessMetadata']['Gateways']

amount_of_gateways = len(gateways)

for gateway in gateways:
    print(gateway["Rssi"])
```